# Sending request with data from other request

Tags: reactjs, react-context, async.js

I have an User context provider where I want to store functions that validate and refresh his JWT token before every request.

Here is template of my code

```
const UserContext = createContext({})

const UserContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tokens")))
    
    // set params for request
    const getParams = (params) => {
        return {
            ...params,
            headers: {
                ...params.headers,
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${user.access}`
            }
        }
    }
    
    // validate token
    const validate = async () => {
        return await fetch(url1, params1)
    }
    
    // refresh token
    const refresh = async () => {
        return await fetch(url2, params2)
    }
    
    // Authorized request. Token is validated, refreshed(if needed) 
    // and used in authorization header during fetch
    const authFetch = async (url, params) => {
        const valid = await validate()
        if(valid){
            return fetch(url, getParams(params))
        }
        else{
            await refresh()
            return fetch(url, getParams(params))
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser, authFetch}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

The problem is that authFetch function is not waiting for validation and refresh functions to complete and returned fetch sends undefined tokens to server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think this could slow down your application a lot, why not decouple refreshing from your regular API calls and have your token refresh on page load with a useEffect or something?

Comment: @fordat Your approach seems to be much better than my, thanks!